# No module named 'imp'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu, import

I have to extend the code that an ancient student done. After installing all the library needed I finally tried the code and got this error :

---

```
$ ./main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    module = _SpecMethods(spec)._load_unlocked()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
    return self._load_backward_compatible()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
    spec.loader.load_module(spec.name)
  File "ExtensionLoader__tkinter.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader__tkinter.py", line 3, in __bootstrap__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named 'imp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/cx_Freeze-4.3.4-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    module = _SpecMethods(spec)._load_unlocked()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
    return self._load_backward_compatible()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
    spec.loader.load_module(spec.name)
  File "/home/aitech/Scrivania/folder_test/GUI_videoServer/mainFrame.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    module = _SpecMethods(spec)._load_unlocked()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
    return self._load_backward_compatible()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
    spec.loader.load_module(spec.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-tk package')
ImportError: No module named 'imp', please install the python3-tk package
```

---

I don't think there is an error in the code as he is already used.
I well installed python3-tk package, I can use it in command code.
In the setting.py of the project there is already the line 'django_admin_bootstrapped' before 'django.contrib.admin' in INSTALLED_APPS = ( )

I am on Ubuntu :

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I am really lost, if someone could help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you'd post this code?

Comment: OK, how you've tried to install it? By apt-get, pip, compiling from sources, or other way?

Comment: there is a main executable in the project and I followed all the step of the documentation , I installed all libraries (Yasm, Libx264, Libfdk-aac, Libmp3lame, Libopus, Libvpx, FFMPEG) with their official storages, python3 with apt-get, Django and Django Admin Bootstrap with pip3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were having the same problem as I was, but my issue was that _tkinter was importing 'imp' without using python's "import" interface, so it wasn't packaged into an executable with py2exe. I resolved this by adding `options = {"includes": ["imp"]}` to my setup function in my setup.py.

If that was not your issue, the only advice I can offer is that imp.py should be in the base directory of your Lib folder in your python install, and you should probably re-install python to fix it.